# How do I say "X doesn't strike me as..." in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

I want to say the following in correct Spanish.

> We will see, but at the moment the only thing that matters is project MMX. Michael doesn't strike me as a man who puts much importance in money.

Can I say: *Veremos, pero en este momento solo importa proyecto mmx. Michael no me parece...*?

I have no idea about the last sentence.

Please give me the correct translation and/or show me better examples. Preferably as short as possible.

(By the way, MMX is a local soccer club)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say:

**Ya** veremos, de momento lo único [que importa / importante] es el proyecto MMX.

Variantes progresivamente cortas:

- No me parece que Michael *sea el tipo de persona que le da* mucha importancia al dinero.
- No me parece que Michael *sea de las personas que le dan* mucha importancia al dinero.
- No me parece que Michael *sea de los que le dan* mucha importancia al dinero.
- No me parece que Michael *le dé* mucha importancia al dinero.

Una construcción alternativa:

- Creo que Michael *no es el tipo de persona que le da* mucha importancia al dinero.
- Creo que Michael *no es de las personas que le dan* mucha importancia al
  dinero.
- Creo que Michael *no es de los que le dan* mucha importancia al
  dinero.
- Creo que Michael *no le da* mucha importancia al dinero.

En mi opinión la tercera variante "*Ser de los que le dan importancia ...*" me resulta la más natural de todas.

**(*) Edited**

"*Michael doesn't strike me as...*" is close to "*I don't think he is...*" / "*No me parece que ...*"

Main clause affirmative variant: "*I think he isn't...*" / "*Creo que Michael no ...*"

Comment: +1 I like your sentences the best so far, but you may want to clarify the 5th to the 8th are closer to the original than the first four. There's a difference between "I don't think he is..." and "I think he isn't...", both in English and in Spanish, and "Michael doesn't strike me as..." is closer to "I don't think he is...". Therefore, it's the main clause the one that should be in negative.

Comment: Thank you @Yay. I totally agree with you. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate `It strikes me that` as

> Me da la impresión de que ...

Applied to your example

> **Me da la impresión** de que Michael not es el tipo de persona que le da mucha importancia al dinero.  <sub>Michael **doesn't strike me as** a man who puts much importance in money.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say this....

> Ya veremos, por el momento lo único que importa es el proyecto MMX. Me parece que Michael tiene poca importancia por el dinero.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone got any other examples?

Comment: `A michael no le importa el dinero, por el momento lo que importa es el proyecto MMX.`  (you can ignore `We will see`)

Answer (score 0):

Translating from English to Spanish is not always an easy task.

- *we will see* is often translated as *lo veremos, ya veremos* or its plain form *veremos*.
- The line

  > *but at the moment the only thing that matters is project MMX*,

  can be translated as *pero por el momento la única cosa que importa es el proyecto MMX*.
- The last line,

  > *Michael doesn't strike me as a man who puts much importance in money'*,

  is perhaps the complex part. The relative pronoun *who* is often translated as plain *que*, and the idiom *doesn't strike me = no me parece*. Putting these together yields,

  > *Michael no me parece como un hombre que pone mucha importancia en el dinero.*

  However, I don't find this sentence much idiomatic. I'd use something like:

  > *No me parece que Michael sea un hombre que ponga mucha importancia en el dinero.*

  Here we triggered the subjunctive.